# How to get whether there are elements left in array or not

Tags: c++11

```
int main()
{
    int arr[10000] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int n = 10;
    
    while(arr[i] != null){
        num = num * n + arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    
    cout << num << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

*It throws error, but i don't know how to get if there're left any elements in my array or not, but i don't want to change null with 0, because it is possible certain element to be 0.*

Comment: Just keep count of the number of elements. You could encapsulate both the array and its size in a struct or a class. Or just use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: C++ raw arrays are fixed length.  Possibly you want a `vector<int>` instead of an array, but if you use an array then you need to manually track how many elements have meaningful values, or you need to set and test for a sentinel value (`0` or `-1` are popular choices for that).  Any way around, `null` is not an `int`, so elements of your `int` array cannot have the value `null`.

Comment: You may want to look at [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your array with a number that you're not going to use. Suppose you do it with `-1` or you can even take `INT_MAX` (max value 32-bit integer can store). 
But keep in mind that in order to use `INT_MAX` you'll need to include the header: `#include<limits.h>`

Now you need to initialize the array either by simply running a loop over the size of the array or by using the [memset](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memset-in-cpp/) function.

Now you can use `while(arr[i] != -1) or while(arr[i] != INT_MAX)`.
The loop will stop after your elements are done processing. That way you'll know if there are elements left in your array.
Hope this helps.